# MySQL - Finding discrepancies in a common value for 2 different tables based on another common value

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, let's call them Table1 and Table2.

Table 1 and Table 2 both have 2 columns of interest (each table has several irrelevant columns as well): tID, xID

Some of the xID values are different between the 2 tables and I need to be able to visualise them in a table, preferably with 3 columns (tID, xID1, xID2) and displaying only values that have a discrepancy.

As the original tables have the same columns of interest, I am unsure if JOIN will just merge the values together or how it will treat the discrepancies.

This is what I have got at the moment, but I am not sure if it will work:

```
SELECT Table1.tID, Table1.xID, Table2.tID, Table2.xID, 
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE
     table1.xID <> Table2.xID
GROUP BY tID
;
```

Could someone please advice me if this will work or what would be the best way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: `WHERE table1.tID = table2.tID AND table1.xID != table2.xID`

Comment: Your code will make a cross product of all the different xID values.